# Android Eraser removes background image how to avoid it

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to erase contents of `Canvas` without erasing the Background Image. I just want to remove drawable content i.e lines, colors etc from canvas. But currently background image also gets erased. Basically what I tried so far is that I created a frame layout and place an `ImageView` over another `ImageView`, considering that if image on top is erased the one below which is exact copy will not be erased.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="310dp">

    <com.almaarijsoft.kanvas.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/drawing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/smoky" />

    <com.almaarijsoft.kanvas.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/drawingViewBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:background="@color/smoky" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and then

```
private Paint drawPaint;
//usage

//set erase true or false
public void setErase(boolean isErase) {
    erase = isErase;
    if (erase) {
        drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    } else{
        drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
    }
}
```

this is how i am setting image to canvas

```
public static void setCanvasFromGalleryImage(Intent data, DrawingView drawView, DrawingView drawView2, Activity activity) {// DrawingView is class extended from View

    if (data != null) {
        // our BitmapDrawable for the thumbnail
        BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = null;
        // try to retrieve the image using the data from the intent
        Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            String fileSrc = cursor.getString(idx);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc); // load
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 750, 600, false);
            drawView.setImage(bitmap);
            drawView2.setImage(bitmap);
            drawView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); // IMPORTANT set hardware acceleration off with this line. Otherwise your view's background will NOT be transparent
            drawView.bringToFront(); //
        } else {
            bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), data.getData().getPath());
            drawView.setImage(bitmap);
        }
    } else {
        MyAppUtil.getToast(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
// inside Drawview following implementation is added by me.
private Canvas drawCanvas;
//start new drawing
public void setImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    drawCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    invalidate();
}
```

loading image from source(gallery) and setting it as background(as bitmap) on canvas

Comment: how are you using your `Paint`?

Comment: nevermind, it seems like you're following some [tuts+ guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/create-a-drawing-app-on-android--cms-704)

Comment: In the linked tutorial `DrawingView` doesn't have `setImage` method. Can you post your implementation? Otherwise is really difficult to help you

Comment: @MattiaMaestrini: please look at the edit that i mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to modify the `setImage` of `DrawingView` like this:

```
public void setImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        this.setBackground(drawable);
    } else {
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

If you set the bitmap as background when you use `setErase(true)` only the content drawn on the canvas will be erased.

And also you don't need need multiple `DrawingView` but only one.

Comment: worked like a charm, can you tell me what was i missing? or if that is not possible can you please tell what you did different?

Comment: Because in your  `setImage` the bitmap is drawn directly on the canvas, when you enable erase mode **everything** on the canvas will be erased, also your image. In my answer's `setImage `instead the bitmap is drawn in the background of the View, it is not part of the canvas, so when you enable erase mode it will not be erased.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your described behavior just by extending ImageView and calling the super method in onDraw.

```
public class DrawingView extends ImageView
```

---

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}
```

---

Set the "background" via the `ImageView`'s methods:

```
drawView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Nothing changed, and yes you are correct i am following the above mentioned tutorial

Comment: If no one can reproduce your issue, then no one can help you. Your question has no relevant code for doing that.

Comment: The issue can be reproduced easily i,e by setting an image as background to Canvas and then try erase the image. The only thing that i want is that i dont want image to get erased. Now i proposed my solution and placed it within my question. Now i was looking for some 1 to point the problem in what i am doing. Or propose a better solution that i cannot find here.

Comment: In my proposed solution, I have delegated the drawing of your background to the `ImageView` class. You can set a bitmap via its `setImageBitmap` method.